# htaccess file adds the virtual directory address to the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I wrote a script to add shtml extension to all requests that don't have it. This is it:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} htmlTemplates
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.shtml$
        RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)$ $1.shtml [r,nc]
</IfModule>
```

I tried it on my local server, which is a virtual location, and it ends up rewriting the url with the system location of the file rather like this:

http://svn1/C:/Documents and Settings/vunsal/My Documents/My Dropbox/Workspace/National Grid/Templating/Svn1/site/index.shtml

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond $0 htmlTemplates
RewriteCond $0 !\.shtml$
RewriteRule .* %{REQUEST_URI}.shtml [R=301,L]
```